# Motion tracking Object Shows up in render but video doesn't

Tags: tracking, compositing-nodes

I made a 3D track of a scene and add an object.

When I hit render to see how the object looks in the video, but I can't see the video, all I see is the object

[image]

When I hit render the video doesn't show up in the background.

[image]

Even with the node compositing done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The render layer has no Alpha Channel. Enable *Film > Transparent*

[image]

[image]